# Merge on substring

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:

df1 with columns A and B and df2 with columns C and D.

I want to merge df1 and df2 under the condition that A contains D.

```
df1 = [['Hello world',10],['bla bla',12],['okey',13]]
df2 = [['rld',100]]
```

Result

```
df_1_2 = [['rld',100,10]]
```

So the result contains all columns of df1 and df2 (except column A of df1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do `findall` find the substring then `merge`

```
df1['new'] = df1[0].str.findall('|'.join(df2[0].tolist())).str[0]
out = df1.merge(df2,left_on='new',right_on=0)
           0_x  1_x  new  0_y  1_y
0  Hello world   10  rld  rld  100
```